# Ciclos While simples

Tags: c, while

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

    int cont=15;
    while(cont<=200){
        printf("%d\n",&cont);
        cont++;     
    }
}
```

Supostamente o contador devia começar com o valor 15 e ir mostrando o seu valor ao adicionar 1 no final de cada ciclo.
Mas quando executo o programa mostra apenas 2293324 em todas as linhas...
Já tentei acrescentar outra váriavel para fazer o quadrado e continua igual.

Answer (score 2):

Remova `&` desta linha `printf("%d\n",&cont);`:

***Código:***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int cont=15;
    while(cont<=200){
        printf("%d\n",cont);
        cont++;     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](http://ideone.com/7RUCSK)

Comment: Ok, já percebi, & só serve para as variáveis dentro do scanf... Obrigado pela ajuda.